# Click open all siblings - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I press on one of the buttons of menu the siblings open. I need each of the buttons to carry their independent content. Right now all the children grouped independently appear together on the father who clicks

This is my code. I edit it to divide it into two questions and not mix content

```
class Nav extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            menuSubmenu:[],
            abrirSubmenu: false,
        }
        this.submenuClick = this.submenuClick.bind(this);
    }
    submenuClick() {
        this.setState(state => ({
            abrirSubmenu: !state.abrirSubmenu
          }));
        //alert('Click!')
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        fetch('fake.php')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(menuSubmenu =>{

            const PadreMap = menuSubmenu.reduce((acc, obj) => {
                if (!acc[obj.Padre]) {
                  acc[obj.Padre] = {
                    ...obj,
                    Hijo: [obj.Hijo],
                    Description: [obj.Description]
                  };
                } else {
                  !acc[obj.Padre].Hijo.includes(obj.Hijo) && acc[obj.Padre].Hijo.push(obj.Hijo);
                  //!acc[obj.Padre].Hijo.includes(obj.Hijo) && acc[obj.Padre].Hijo.push(obj.Description)
                }
                return acc;
              }, {});

                this.setState({
                        menuSubmenu: Object.keys(PadreMap).map((padre) => ({
                        menu: padre,
                        submenu: PadreMap[padre].Hijo,
                        id: PadreMap.Id,
                        descripcion: PadreMap[padre].Description,
                        url: PadreMap[padre].URL
                }))

            })
            console.log(PadreMap);
        })
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.menuSubmenu.length > 0) {
          return(
            <nav className="nav">
                <div className="menu">
                    <ul className="list">
                        {this.state.menuSubmenu.map(datos => <Menu key={datos.id} menu={datos.menu} submenu={datos.submenu} descripcion={datos.descripcion} submenuClick={this.submenuClick} abrirSubmenu={this.state.abrirSubmenu}/>)}
                    </ul>
                    <div className="content-bnt">
                        <button id="desplegar" className='btn btn--rounded'>
                            <Icon icon="flecha" className='ico-flecha'/>
                        </button>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </nav>
          );
        }
        return (<p>Cargando usuarios...</p>);
    }
}

class Menu extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <li key={this.props.id} className="list__item">
                <button title={this.props.menu} id={"mn-" + this.props.menu} className="desplegable" onClick={this.props.submenuClick}><Icon icon="auriculares" className='ico-auriculares'/>{this.props.menu}</button>
            {
            this.props.abrirSubmenu
                ? (
                <div id="sb-crm" className="submenu">
                    {this.props.submenu.map(hijo => <h3 className="nav--title"><Icon icon="descargar" className='ico-descargar'/>{hijo}</h3>)}
                    <ul className="list">
                        <li className="list__item">
                            {this.props.descripcion.map(tercerNivel => <a href={this.props.url} title={this.props.descripcion}>{tercerNivel}</a>)}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                )
                : (
                null
                )
            }
            </li>
        )
    }
}

export default Nav;
```

I also need that by clicking on each of the buttons (Padre) hide the content of the other parents (Padre) and show only yours. Right now it does not work and ALL parents (Padre) content is displayed when any button is pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each parent needs to have their own state.

```
const padreState = {};
// crear estado para cada padre
Object.keys(PadreMap).forEach(item => {
  padreState['padre-' + PadreMap[item].Id] = false;
});

this.setState({
  menuSubmenu: Object.keys(PadreMap).map(padre => ({
    menu: padre,
    submenu: PadreMap[padre].Hijo,
    id: PadreMap[padre].Id, // cambiaron desde PadreMap.Id
    descripcion: PadreMap[padre].Description,
    url: PadreMap[padre].URL
  })),
  padreState: padreState
});
```

sub menu onclick

```
toggle = padreState => {
  Object.keys(padreState).forEach(item => {
    padreState[item] = false;
  });
};

submenuClick(padre) {

  const { padreState } = this.state;
  const corriente = { ...padreState };

  const toggle = !corriente[padre];

  this.toggle(corriente); // toggle menu items
  corriente[padre] = toggle;

  this.setState({
    padreState: corriente
  });
  //alert('Click!')
}
```

call the function like, in your `<Menu .../>`

```
submenuClick={() => this.submenuClick('padre-' + datos.id)}
abrirSubmenu={this.state.padreState['padre-' + datos.id]}
```

full code

```
class Nav extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      menuSubmenu: [],
      abrirSubmenu: false,
      padreState: {}
    };
    this.submenuClick = this.submenuClick.bind(this);
  }

  toggle = padreState => {
    Object.keys(padreState).forEach(item => {
      padreState[item] = false;
    });
  };

  submenuClick(padre) {

    const { padreState } = this.state;
    const corriente = { ...padreState };

    const toggle = !corriente[padre];

    this.toggle(corriente);
    corriente[padre] = toggle;

    this.setState({
      padreState: corriente
    });
    //alert('Click!')
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('fake.php')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(menuSubmenu => {
        const PadreMap = menuSubmenu.reduce((acc, obj) => {
          if (!acc[obj.Padre]) {
            acc[obj.Padre] = {
              ...obj,
              Hijo: [obj.Hijo],
              Description: [obj.Description]
            };
          } else {
            !acc[obj.Padre].Hijo.includes(obj.Hijo) &&
              acc[obj.Padre].Hijo.push(obj.Hijo);
            //!acc[obj.Padre].Hijo.includes(obj.Hijo) && acc[obj.Padre].Hijo.push(obj.Description)
          }
          return acc;
        }, {});

        const padreState = {};
        // crear estado para cada padre
        Object.keys(PadreMap).forEach(item => {
          padreState['padre-' + PadreMap[item].Id] = false;
        });

        this.setState({
          menuSubmenu: Object.keys(PadreMap).map(padre => ({
            menu: padre,
            submenu: PadreMap[padre].Hijo,
            id: PadreMap[padre].Id, // cambiaron desde PadreMap.Id
            descripcion: PadreMap[padre].Description,
            url: PadreMap[padre].URL
          })),
          padreState: padreState
        });
        console.log(PadreMap);
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.menuSubmenu.length > 0) {
      return (
        <nav className="nav">
          <div className="menu">
            <ul className="list">
              {this.state.menuSubmenu.map(datos => (
                <Menu
                  key={datos.id}
                  menu={datos.menu}
                  submenu={datos.submenu}
                  descripcion={datos.descripcion}
                  submenuClick={() => this.submenuClick('padre-' + datos.id)}
                  abrirSubmenu={this.state.padreState['padre-' + datos.id]}
                />
              ))}
            </ul>
            <div className="content-bnt">
              <button id="desplegar" className="btn btn--rounded">
                <Icon icon="flecha" className="ico-flecha" />
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      );
    }
    return <p>Cargando usuarios...</p>;
  }
}

class Menu extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <li key={this.props.id} className="list__item">
        <button
          title={this.props.menu}
          id={'mn-' + this.props.menu}
          className="desplegable"
          onClick={this.props.submenuClick}
        >
          <Icon icon="auriculares" className="ico-auriculares" />
          {this.props.menu}
        </button>
        {this.props.abrirSubmenu ? (
          <div id="sb-crm" className="submenu">
            {this.props.submenu.map(hijo => (
              <h3 className="nav--title">
                <Icon icon="descargar" className="ico-descargar" />
                {hijo}
              </h3>
            ))}
            <ul className="list">
              <li className="list__item">
                {this.props.descripcion.map(tercerNivel => (
                  <a href={this.props.url} title={this.props.descripcion}>
                    {tercerNivel}
                  </a>
                ))}
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </li>
    );
  }
}

export default Nav;
```